# React-native-navigation goBack() irregular

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I encountered a problem when using
`"@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.11.1"`and`"@react-navigation/native": "^5.8.9"`
[snack.expo.io](https://snack.expo.io/@zhzh/ashamed-orange)
the operation is as follows:

1. After entering the main interface, click the tabBar `B PAGE` bottom
2. Click `jump to B Detail`
3. Click the headerRight custom `Back` button

Why do I return to the A page? When I click the B page button at the bottom again, I will jump to the Detail page. I don’t know why. Can you help me?

Answer (score 2):

I think it's because you are using `navigate.goBack()`; it pops the last item in the stack and navigate to that; so when you're trying to use bottom tabs for navigation, you push a new screen to the stack which gets rendered on `goBack()`;

consider using the screen name instead;

Comment: how to push a new screen to the stack ? please

Comment: @ZhihaoZhang when you navigate to a page, you push that into a stack in which you can navigate back to the page you were in;